# Array Index as Keys in Hash Tables

Tags: perl, hashtable, associative-array

I'm trying to work with hash tables in perl. I'm facing a problem when i'm using an array index as a key in the hash table.

```
my @array;
my %Mappings;
$Mappings{$array[0]} = 'First';
$Mappings{$array[1]} = 'Second';
print "$Mappings{$array[0]} \n $Mappings{$array[1]} \n";
```

The output of this code is always Second. I'm unable to access the value First with this code.

Should I be considering any other steps to access the value First ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your elements have the same value, e.g., undef, 1, 2, 'a' ... then you will get the same hash. To avoid this you can use the address of the array element:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @array = ('1', '1');
my %Mappings;
$Mappings{\$array[0]} = 'First';
$Mappings{\$array[1]} = 'Second';
print "$Mappings{\$array[0]} \n $Mappings{\$array[1]} \n";
```

Comment: Your answer does the job ! To clarify your explanation, you mean, if my array elements have the same value, they end up getting the same hash ?

Comment: that's right, if your keys are identical then you will fetch the same value.

Answer (score 3):

Given both `$array[0]` and `$array[1]` are undefined, they'll map to an empty string for hash access. So yeah it is expected that they'll refer to the same element.

Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an array that contains a set of elements. I'm trying to make these elements as Keys for the hash table. I was thinking if it would be possible to access the values of the hash table this way.